# Exceptions not displayed when running Delphi app

Tags: delphi, exception, tethering

I'm running Delphi 10.2 Tokyo's sample tethering app

C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Tethering\PhotoWall\Mobile

When running normally on Windows and an iPad, the app runs without errors but does not function.

When run with the debugger (on both Windows and iPad) it gets error messages like these:

Debugger Exception Notification

Project MobilePhotoApp raised exception class EIdSocketError with message 'Socket Error # 48 
Address already in use.'.

Project MobilePhotoApp raised exception class EIdCouldNotBindSocket with message 'Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use.'.

How do I get the app to show these errors when it is deployed normally without the debugger?[image]

Comment: Are these exceptions "surfacing" when run in debugger, error dialogs appearing?

Comment: You should get those, unless you capture and swallow them using a `try..except` block or in the `Application.OnException` event handler.

Comment: Yes, these exceptions "surface" when run in the debugger. The error dialogs do not appear when run normally.

Comment: I guess you need to change the code that handles those exceptions. We can't see your code.

Comment: The source has only two "try... finally" pairs which free an object. 

I'm in agreement that I should get those errors unless they are captured and ignored by try...except. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: You can see the code if you have Delphi 10.2. It has not been modified.

Comment: That's not really how we roll here. Question should stand alone. We would need a [mcve] for this to be a valid question here.

Comment: The question should stand alone. It does require that one uses Delphi though, which comes with this (relatively) minimal complete and verifiable example.

Comment: It appears to be trying to use port 2020. You must already have another app using that port. Strangely, this is coming from Indy, yet I don't see anything in either of these sample apps which use Indy.

Comment: I was specifically asking because a 'Debugger Exception Notification' like in your question is not surfacing, it is something internally used by the debugger (and can be disabled for exception types). When not handled the exception that triggered this internal debugger notification dialog will normally cause an actual error dialog, which can be seen by the user. And seems to be missing here.

Comment: Actually it appears `IPPeer` internally uses Indy. Further, I can't find where port `2020` is referenced either.

Comment: This machine is using a trial version of Delphi which doesn't come with source code. Perhaps this is normal behavior for exceptions when the source for the code throwing the exception is not available?

Comment: Found it. It seems the tethering library in Delphi hard-coded this port, and a few others too. `System.Tether.NetworkAdapter` has `TTetheringNetworkAdapterCommon` which references these port numbers.

Comment: I'm running only Delphi 10.2 (trial) on this Windows 10 machine with nothing else installed beyond EditPad Lite. I don't know what would be using that port. (I'm also not at all familiar with networking so I don't really know what a port is.)
Is there a way to modify these ports without access to the source code?

Comment: I would imagine it being absolutely impossible to use this tethering library in its current state in your scenario, hence the +1 to your question. Someone made some poor decisions while designing it.

Comment: Please do not post images of your code and error messages. This [Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) contains a list of the many reasons why images of code are useless to us. An [mcve] consists of code, in your post, properly formatted as such. Error/exception messages should be copied and pasted as text as well; with one of the exception dialogs open, hitting Ctrl+C will copy a text version of the dialog into the clipboard for you.

Comment: The debugger sees all exceptions before the app does. The app user only sees exceptions that are raised in the context of the UI thread and are not caught by UI code but are caught by default handlers inside the RTL. If the debugger shows an exception that does not appear to the app user, it means the exception is being caught somewhere by the app. In this case, if your own code doesn't see the socket exception, it means it is being caught internally by the tethering library. I suggest you configure the debugger to ignore that exception

Comment: The tethering support tries ports in the range 2020-2039 for the "manager", one-by-one until it finds one it can use. For each port that is in use, it will raise the exception you're seeing, however the application handles the exception, which is why you do not see it in the application.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a number of contributors in the comments, this is what seems to be the answer.

The exceptions are likely being handled inside the network library as it searches for a free port.

I assumed the exceptions were explaining the issue with lack of tethering on Windows 10. However, the mobile app does pair successfully (to the desktop companion running on either a Windows 7 machine or a Macintosh) when the mobile app is run on an Android or an iPad. The issue with lack of pairing is then very likely related to the firewall on the Windows 10 machine.

I've asked about how to get Windows 10 or its firewall to grant access to a Delphi tethering app in this question: [Delphi apps won't tether on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166086/delphi-apps-wont-tether-on-windows-10)

Comment: It turns out McAfee Internet was blocking the Delphi tethering apps. Once  McAfee was removed, Windows asked for a firewall exception and allowed the tethering apps to pair.

Neither McAfee nor the Delphi tethering apps showed any error message when pairing failed.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why you don't get any errors when running your app without the debugger attached to it is because the application itself is designed in a way to handle those exceptions on its own.

Based on exceptions names I'm guessing that they are coming from Indy networking library. Indy is a third party networking library that ships with Delphi. Most Indy components are designed in a way to never raise any exceptions since they are handled internally.

You should generally check the component documentation to see the proper way of handling errors. But this could be problematic to you since Indy components are being internally used by Tethering components which complicated everything a lot.

Any way the most likely cause for the example application of not being able to connect is the fact that Indy components quickly raise internal exception and abandon connection attempts if they are being blocked by firewall. In fact this often happens so quickly that your firewall won't even ask you whether you want to allow your program to establish that network connection or not.
This is one of the reasons why I don't like working with Indy components since my Eset Smart Security never shows the confirmation dialog fast enough for me to allow establishing of network connection. So I need to add this application to firewall exception before I try doing anything with Indy components.

Comment: "Most Indy components are designed in a way to **never raise any exceptions** since they are handled internally." I find that statement false. Of course they raise exceptions. The subject is whether those exceptions are handled or not.

Comment: I have run that mobile tethering Photowall app on an iPad using the debugger. I get similar results to the errors from Windows 10. Does that mean the iPad is having the same issues that Windows is having?

I'm still not clear why the exceptions appear when run in the debugger but not when run normally.

Comment: @MikeatBookup To tell you the truth I don't know if the reason for the Photowall application could be the same as on Windows because I personally don't have any experience in mobile development nor do I have ability to test it out. So you will have to make your own little test application using Indy UDP component that tries to work on same port range in order to see if debugger will capture same exceptions.

Comment: @MikeatBookup As for why the exceptions still appear when the application is ran though the debugger. Debugger will always catch any exceptions whether they are handled by application or not. In fact the code to handle the captured exceptions will run only after you click continue or try to step forward in Delphi after the exception was detected. The only way for debugger not to capture certain exception is to order it to ignore certain types of exceptions. And you can do this by changing Delphi options in Tools->Options->Debugger Options->Language Exceptions