# Delphi apps won't tether on Windows 10

Tags: delphi, tethering

How do I get Windows 10 or its firewall to allow my Delphi 10.2 tethering app to get access to the internet?

When either the desktop or the mobile app is run on Windows 10, there is no request for permission from the firewall and tethering fails.

In contrast, the Delphi mobile Photowall tethering example runs fine on Android and iPad, tethering with the matching desktop application on Windows 7 and MacOS. On Windows 7 and Macintosh, the firewall asks for permission when the app is run.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I do get a firewall prompt on Windows 10, just like on previous Windows versions. Are you really sure you did not accidently dismiss the Dialoge? If in doubt, check the list of allowed applications in the built-in Windows firewall.

Comment: I am certain that the dialog has never appeared on this Windows 10 machine for any Delphi tethering app I've made.

I tried adding them manually to the list of app exceptions in the Windows 10 firewall. The apps still will not pair.

Comment: Those same apps pair fine when copied to a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Can't you post a simple example of what is necessary to reproduce the issue? I have never bothered with Embarcadero's tethering components and don't know how to use them.

Comment: Yes, I can post a simple example of app tethering that does not work on this Windows 10 machine. I've tried all of the sample tethering apps (which all work when the .exe files are run on a Windows 7 machine).
Here are the steps for the simplest example which also fails to tether on the Windows 10 machine but works on the Windows 7 machine. http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1842

Comment: I've also wiped out (reset) the Windows 10 machine and still no tethering apps will pair.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows 10 machine in question automatically installed McAfee internet. I uninstalled McAfee and the Delphi tethering apps immediately triggered Firewall exception request and then worked properly.

Even though I added the Delphi tethering apps to the Windows firewall exception list, McAfee apparently still blocked the apps. The Delphi apps never raised an error when blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The app tethering discovery works by using UDP to broadcast a discovery message across **ports 2020-2040**.

The default timeout for the manager discovery period is 1500 milliseconds. The default timeout for the profiles discovery is 5000 milliseconds. Make sure that you open up the app tethering ports in your firewall if they are not already open. If your network is busy, you might want to set the discovery timeout longer than 1500 milliseconds (I normally use 3000 milliseconds at work and the default at home).